# Storing arbitrary complex objects in c# to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am currently programming to multiple API's. Till now I have created classes that use EF syntax (id = classNameId etc...) and convert whatever item is being returned to EF object. Since I'm using the C# Wrappers (created by whatever company created the API) for the API's I can't simply alter whatever class it is that I want to store to the database to use EF Syntax. Is there any project that would allow me to dynamically generate tables and columns for any generic object using run time reflection?

Keep in mind that many of the complex objects have within them complex objects.

As of right now I'm considering writing a script to generate inherited classes for each of the Complex Types (identified via reflection) and inserting a Id (and whetever other information EF would need to generate DB) into the inherited class. This would get a little complicated as it would require implicit conversions for Ienumerable to Ienumerable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

What you actually need is some schema-less database, like MongoDB or RavenDb instead of relational. These allows to do exactly what you said in the title: to store arbitraty complex objects in db.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'd really like to stay within relational databases. The problem that I'm running into is the lack of id field for the complex object (and sub-objects). I'm looking for some way for that field to simply be placed there in EF's inherited class for storage purposes. From what I've learned of MongoDb that is done behind the scenes (the assigning of a id for a document)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at [OrmLite](https://code.google.com/p/servicestack/wiki/OrmLite) and see if it meets your reqs.

```
public class SimpleExample
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
}

//Set once before use (i.e. in a static constructor).
OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider = new SqliteOrmLiteDialectProvider();

using (IDbConnection db = "/path/to/db.sqlite".OpenDbConnection())
using (IDbCommand dbConn = db.CreateCommand())
{
        dbConn.CreateTable<SimpleExample>(true);
        dbConn.Insert(new SimpleExample { Id=1, Name="Hello, World!"});
        var rows = dbConn.Select<SimpleExample>();

        Assert.That(rows, Has.Count(1));
        Assert.That(rows[0].Id, Is.EqualTo(1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as mentioned on their website "For simplicity, and to be able to have the same POCO class persisted in db4o, memcached, redis or on the filesystem (i.e. providers included in ServiceStack), each model must have an 'Id' property which is its **primary key**." The Objects I'm dealing with won't necessarily have this field, I guess if extension properties existed this whole concept would be allot easier. (I'm saying that in a theoretical sense I don't mean to open a discussion on the limitations of extension properties even if they existed)

Comment: I'm fairly certain that if an Id field is not defined in the class it is created automatically on the table by the ORM.